# Visual Studio Configuration Manager Select/Deselect all the projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've got almost 100 projects in my solution, and it usually takes around 5 minutes to build all the projects. So, normally I'll open the configuration manager, and deselect the projects that I want to exclude from the build, and will build the solution. Selecting or deselecting each and every project is painful, please let me know if there is a way to select or deselect all the projects.

Comment: I would suggest keep a set of solution files which include only relevant projects. I believe you do not need 100 projects each time you're working with a code base

Comment: I wish I could do that, but the management is not interested in that :(

Comment: Management shold not care such small technical details, do you have continuous. integration

Comment: Yes, we do have continuous integration.

Comment: so there are should not be any problems by maintaining separate solutions, continuous integrations till build common "God-Solution" and you can develop using more granular solutions

Comment: ...so any actual answers to the question or just suggestions to do things a different way? I was hoping there would be a plugin or something that would allow this.

Answer (score 1):

we have over a hundred projects and i had the same issue

then realised you can just uncheck the first item, then press sequence:

- down arrow
- space bar

...repeatedly.  Makes it a very fast operation.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your solution using [Solution Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can then unload all the projects in a folder by right-clicking on it and selecting Unload All Projects. Then those projects are not rebuilt and you do not need to change anything in the Configuration Manager.